# How to encode emoji while sending to server (Ruby on Rails)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ruby-on-rails, iphone, ruby

While I am sending the emoji to server "\ud83d\ude0e" (emoji unicode) in the given format, the server could not understand the code and while sending push notification from server to device, the notification is not coming.

I have used :

```
NSData *data = [self.activeTextField.text dataUsingEncoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];
NSString *goodValue = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

to encode the message(emoji) while sending and used:

```
NSData *data = [strReceivedMsg dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *goodValue = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];
```

while receiving the messages.

Please suggest how to resolve this issue

Thanks

Comment: What are the actual bytes being received by the server, and do your HTTP (I'm assuming we're talking about HTTP here) headers declare the correct character encoding?

Comment: We are using web socket to transfer message. Actually it's a chatting functionality. So when I am sending an emoji over socket, the server is getting the uni code and "\" is being escaped by "\\" which is unrecognised  by iOS. So what will be the standard format to send emoji which will be supported by server as well as in cross platform also

Comment: What do you mean by "the server could not understand the code"? Are you getting an error message? I'm not well-versed in iOS development but the encoding `NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding` is suspect. If you have emoji then your string isn't ASCII.

Comment: I had gone through some links and I found that.The emoji string mightn't be ASCII, but I'm not getting any idea what will be the encoding format.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
NSString *string = @"This is \u00B7";
```

Instead of \u00B7 add your unicode value. Its working solution.

Comment: Pushkraj, u r saying to add "\ud83d\ude0e" code. I am sending this already

Answer (score 0):

In swift :

Encoding : -

```
 let messageData = chatTextView.text.dataUsingEncoding(NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding)
        let finalMessage = String(data: messageData!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

Decoding : -

```
 let data : NSData = str.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
            let message = String(data: data, encoding: NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding)
```